# Problems with the SASS generator .sass-cache file Liferay 6.2

Tags: sass, liferay, liferay-6, compass-sass, liferay-theme

Good afternoon,

I have problems with the Liferay 6.2 sass generator.

In production I make any CSS in the portlet changes and I can not see the changes in the browser "clearing cache". I go to tomcat webapps and I see that the changes are correct, and that it has deployed well.

But when I go to the browser and access the server I see that the changes in CSS are the old ones.

I have also manually set up the .sass-cache file but it does not play my browser changes.

I think the solution would be to delete the portlet from the webapss and re-deploy .. but of course it is production ..

Do you know any other way ??? Has it happened ??

A greeting!!

Comment: Do you mean that you're changing the file directly in the webapps folder and expect it to be picked up? As you say it's production, I would be shocked if anybody with production access does this kind of nonmaintainable intervention instead of proper deployment.

Comment: No sir. What I'm saying is that I'm doing a deployment in jenkins from portlet to production. But you do not see the changes in my browser, you do not change the .sass-cache of my css. The only solution I have seen is to delete the portlet and return to deploy, but I would like to listen to other solutions without having to delete the portlet and with that deployment change in the browser. @OlafKock

Comment: I'm testing them in a pre-production environment. But the same happens to me of css in both pre and production :) @OlafKock

Comment: Yes it was an issue with 6.1 version,curious to know,how are u making css changes to prod env?

Comment: I'm actually adding a few classes for css from the main.css of the portlet. I'm working with SASS "http://www.javasavvy.com/liferay-gulp-tasks/" on the themes. But in portlets I'm using your main.css file in normal CSS. What happens when I compile with jenkins, I generate a file inside the CSS that is called .sass-cache.

This file is the one used by the browser through the theme and is the one that when deployed does not change. The one that if it changes is the CSS, since in webapps, of the deployment I change the new characteristics of the css @shivam-aggarwal. I'm used Liferay 6.2